# How to determine OpenSUSE package maintainer?

Tags: linux, opensuse, packages, zypper

According to the [Zypper Cheat Sheet](https://en.opensuse.org/images/3/30/Zypper-cheat-sheet-2.pdf), we can use `zypper info` to get package information. Unfortunately, I am not getting results back when using it:

```
> zypper info cryptopp
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

package 'cryptopp' not found.

> zypper info crypto++
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

package 'crypto++' not found.

> zypper info libcryptopp
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

package 'libcryptopp' not found.

> zypper info libcrypto++
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

package 'libcrypto++' not found.
```

I also used the online [OpenSUSE Package Seach](https://software.opensuse.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=crypto%2B%2B&search_devel=false) and got no results.

How do we determine the contact information of a package maintainer under OpenSUSE?

(We believe OpenSUSE carries the project because we get an occasional bug report under the platform. See, for example, [AutoSeededRandomPool::GenerateBlock causes Segmentation Fault/Freeze](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/68)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I wanted to find the package *maintainer*, I would first find *which* package the library belongs to.

For instance, if you are already on OpenSUSE, the place to start is with the library file itself, e.g.,

```
rpm -qf library-filename
```

that is, *library-filename* is the actual name of the file you are interested in.  That rpm command identifies the name of the package.

Once you have the package name, then you can search in the appropriate place for it.

By the way, your search link produced these results:

- [libcrypto++9](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libcrypto++9)
- [libcrypto++-dev](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libcrypto++-dev)

but using the actual package name, you might have seen this:

- [libcryptopp - Crypto++ Library](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libcryptopp)

After having found the appropriate package, you might find the maintainer information in the source's ".spec" file.  rpmfind.net or [rpmbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=libcryptopp) seem to usually have links for this, e.g.,

- [libcryptopp-devel-5.6.2-7.4.1 RPM for aarch64](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/13.2/aarch64/libcryptopp-devel-5.6.2-7.4.1.aarch64.html)

  Changelog

  - Wed Jul 08 2015 bwiedemann@suse.com

    - prevent timing attack to get secret key (bnc#936435, CVE-2015-2141)
      add libcryptopp-CVE-2015-2141.patch
  - Fri Aug 15 2014 sfalken@opensuse.org

    - Added 0001-disable_os_rng_test.patch
      Fixes buildfailure on openSUSE_Factory x86_64 within OBS environment,
      due to OS supplied Random Number Generator taking too long to respond

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why the distros make is so difficult to find contact information. The obvious place (to me) is the package. I despise the greedy "contact me" model, where I have to do something different for each distro. It waste too much of my time. (The other option is to say "screw it", which does not help anyone).